# MySQL to JPA/JPQL query

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, jpql

I try to transform my Mysql query into JPQL, but I don't know which tool can be used on eclipse without compiling.

My logg doesn't tell me where is the error, so I can't find where is the wrong syntax.

This is my query : "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM computer c LEFT JOIN company comp ON c.company_id = comp.id where c.name like ?"

I tried like this : 
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM computer c LEFT JOIN company comp ON c.company_id = comp.id where c.name like :filter"

but it doesn't works.

Computer class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="computer")
//@NamedQuery(name="computer.rowsWithFilter", query="select count(c.id) from computer c left join company comp on c.company_id = comp.id where c.name like :filter") 
public class Computer {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="introduced")
    private LocalDate introduced;

    @Column(name="discontinued")
    private LocalDate discontinued;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;
```

Company class :

@Entity
@Table(name ="company")

```
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You can use `Hibernate Tools`. Please, add your entities.

Comment: Please check answers.

Comment: If you don't mind... in order to let know the community that this question already has an answer... upvote and mark as correct the answer you consider fullfilled your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id) 
FROM computer c 
LEFT JOIN c.company comp
where c.name like :filter
```

Comment: Why do you have an ON clause on the JOIN? if joining across a relation no ON is required in JPQL

Comment: should just be "LEFT JOIN c.company comp" and skip the next line